# Get last record from mongodb collection

Tags: database, mongodb, collections, record

I created a mongo database with a collection called 'rooms'.
I want to get the last room to create the id of the next one.
You can see my disgusting code right down:

**Room schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RoomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    users: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }],
    messages: {
        type: [String]
    },
    subject: {
        type: String
    },
    id: {
        type: Number
    }
});

var Room = module.exports = mongoose.model('Room', RoomSchema);

module.exports.createRoom = function (newRoom, callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newRoom.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            newRoom.password = hash;
            newRoom.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

**Trying to get the last room**

```
var lastRoom = Room.find({}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1);
```

Then I tried to run it and output the 'lastRoom', I got this:

```
the last room was: [object Object]
```

What should I do?

Comment: I do it on backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use callback after the query

```
Room.find({}).sort({ natural:-1 }).limit(1).then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

try this: var lastRoom = Room.find({}).sort(['id',1]).limit(1);

Comment: `Error: Invalid sort() argument, must be array of arrays`

Comment: try this: var lastRoom = Room.find({}).sort({'id':-1}).limit(1);

Comment: `the last room was: [object Object]` :/

Comment: can you try to console it like this : console.log(lastRoom);                                  
 what do you see from console log?

Comment: A strange output, its seems that he did not found it. (its too long to put it here)

Comment: `Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection {
     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
     opts:
      { bufferCommands: true,
        capped: false,
        '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
     name: 'rooms',
     collectionName: 'rooms',
     conn:
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: 'login'...`

Comment: could you try this: var lastRoom = Room.findOne({}); and  console.log(lastRoom);   to make sure that we return any object

Comment: i think you have some problem with database connection or schema design could you check for that